# How can I create a Test scenario in JMeter where multiple users login and logout concurrently for a certain ramp up time?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-plugins, performance-testing, blazemeter

I am a complete newbie in JMeter or load testing in general.

The JMeter Test scenario i want to create:-

- 1. **50 different users**(having different login credentials) login into a
        web application - do some stuff - then logout continuously for 30 
        minutes.Each User repeats this loop (**Login - do stuff- logout**) again and again for 30 minutes simultaneously/concurrently.

     2. Each user does the exact same thing like adding a new 
        customer/profile.
     3. Each user then does a logout from the application.

Now, i tried to record this from JMeter script recorder, but after i setup proxy in the Chrome browser, i could not open my demo/test website.

So, i tried to use "**Blazemeter**" and recorded the whole scenario with 1 user 
 but was not able to export the .jmx file in JMeter as file cant be downloaded it says "failed - network error". I don't know what to do next and how to proceed further.

**Queries:-**

- 1. Should i create a "**CSV Config Data set**" element and store all
     different credentials in it? How can i achieve this. **I have 3 login
     parameters like portal id, userid and password**. joeportal345,
     joeuser445, password556(ex)
  2. The "**Enter password" page comes after user enters 2 ID**'s. Also, how can i capture the login/save buttons?
  3. How can i use the recorded scenario from Blazemeter and **plug in different 50 login credentials at the same time**?
  4. Do i need to create **user defined variables**?
  5. Can any **JMeter plugin** make this task easier?
  6. Do i need to use any **Logic controllers** like Loop controller, simple controller etc.

**Please reply so that i can atleast get started**? I have gone through many tutorials, articles on the web, but still cant get hold of it and failed to create the script?

Comment: did you managed to this scenario? I need some guidance, thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. The relevant [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) configuration would be something like:

   [image]
2. You should create a CSV file and put your credentials there. Then you can load the file using [CSV Data Set Config](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG)
3. JMeter doesn't click any buttons or type anything into inputs, it acts on HTTP protocol level, to wit it sends associated [HTTP Requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) and waits for responses. When you click a button a HTTP Request is being sent to the server so you need to ensure that JMeter sends the same request as browser does. You might need to perform some [correlation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) as well
4. User Defined Variables is not mandatory, if you have some values which are reused between requests - better go for [HTTP Request Defaults](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults)
5. I'm not aware of any plugins, you can try using [BlazeMeter Proxy Recorder which can perform automatic correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-cut-your-jmeter-scripting-time-80/), however if you cannot download generated files it won't be useful
6. For your simple scenario you don't need any logic controllers

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with Taurus [as I describe here](https://github.com/djangofan/run-taurus),  but the suggestion by Dmitri T is probably quicker/easier.

https://github.com/djangofan/run-taurus/blob/2d2865c72320fb8004c950adb54b3d4565669913/testit-cloud.yml#L8-L17